# Perl: dispatch hashes and shared variables

Tags: perl, variables, scope, anonymous-function

I have a module with a set of functions implemented as a dispatch hash with a helper function thus:

```
my $functions = {
  'f1' => sub { 
      my %args = @_;
      ## process data ...
      return $answer; 
  },
[etc.]
};

sub do_function {
    my $fn = shift;
    return $functions->{$fn}(@_);
}
```

This is used by some scripts that process tab-delimited data; the column being examined is converted by the appropriate subroutine. When processing a value in a column, I pass a hash of data to the sub, and it generates a scalar, the new value for the column.

Currently the subs are called thus:

```
my $new_value = do_function( 'f1', data => $data, errs => $errs );
```

and the variables in the arguments are all declared as 'my' - my $data, my $errs, etc.. Is it possible to update other values in the arguments that are passed into the subs without having to return them? i.e. instead of having to do this:

```
 ... in $functions->{f1}:
      my %args = @_;
      ## process data ...
      ## alter $args{errs}
      $args{errs}->{type_one_error}++; 
      ## ...
      return { answer => $answer, errs => $args{errs} }; 
 ...

 ## call the function, get the response, update the errs
 my $return_data = do_function( 'f1', data => $data, errs => $errs );
 my $new_value = $return_data->{answer};
 $errs = $return_data->{errs}; ## this has been altered by sub 'f1'
```

I could do this:

```
  my $new_value = do_function( 'f1', data => $data, errs => $errs );
  ## no need to update $errs, it has been magically updated already!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass reference to value and update it inside of subroutine.

For example:

```
sub update {
    my ($ref_to_value) = @_;
    $$ref_to_value = "New message";
    return "Ok";
}

my $message = "Old message";

my $retval = update(\$message);

print "Return value: '$retval'\nMessage: '$message'\n";
```

And as far as I can see from your code snippets, `$errs` is already reference to hash.
So, actually, all you have to do - just comment out line `$errs = $return_data->{errs};` and try

If I get your code right, `$errs` gets updated. And then you should just change your return value to `$answer` and do:

```
my $new_value = do_function( 'f1', data => $data, errs => $errs );
```

Comment: Yes, it has made my perl life most delightful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- first change your definition of `do_function` to:

  ```
  sub do_function {
      my $fn = shift;
      goto &{$functions->{$fn}}
  }
  ```

  that is the proper way to dispatch to a new subroutine.  this form of `goto` replaces the currently executing subroutine with the new coderef, passing `@_` unchanged, and removing `do_function` from the call stack (so `caller` works right).  you probably want some error checking in there too, to make sure that `$fn` is a valid name.
- inside your function, you can simply modify cells of `@_` directly, and you do not need to pass anything by reference (since perl already did that for you).

  ```
  sub add1 {$_[0]++}
  my $x = 1;
  add1 $x;
  say $x; # 2
  ```

  to support `key => value` arguments without passing by reference you could write it this way:

  ```
  in $functions->{f1}:
    my %args;
    while (@_) {
        $args{$_} = /errs/ ? \shift : shift for shift
    }
    ## process data ...
    ## alter ${$args{errs}}
    ## ...
  ```
- **HOWEVER** since in your case `$errs` is a hash reference, you don't need to do any extra work.  all references are passed by reference automatically.  in your existing code, all you have to do is modify a key of `$args{errs}` (as you are doing right now) and it will modify every reference to that hash.

  if you wanted a function local hash, you need to make a copy of the hash*:

  ```
  my %errs = %{$args{errs}};
  ```

  where `%errs` is private, and once you are done, you can push any values you want to make public into `$args{errs}` with `$args{errs}{...} = ...;`.  but be sure not to replace `$args{errs}` with the copy (as in `$args{errs} = \%errs`) since that will break the connection to the caller's error hash.  if you want to copy all the new values in, you could use one of:

  ```
  %{$args{errs}} = %errs;                             # replace all keys
  @{$args{errs}}{keys %errs} = values %errs;          # replace keys in %errs
  ... and $args{errs}{$_} = $errs{$_} for keys %errs; # conditional replace
  ```

  *or localize some/all of the keys

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response!

Comment: I used this code again today -- thank you again for this very useful explanation!